# angularjs $http post request making string data into an object

Tags: php, angularjs

When I send data into PHP file using AngularJS $http post, the data type is supposed to be a string. But when I try to get the output data from PHP file (I just simply echo `$_POST['string']`) by the then function, it automatically changes to `[object Object]` type somehow.

Here is the code:

JS:

```
$http({
                method:"POST",
                type:"json",
                url:"./forms/crud.php",
                data:{id:cId}
            }).then(function (d) {
                alert(d.config.data.id);
                console.log(d);
            })
```

PHP:

```
if(is_post_quest()){
    echo $_POST['id'];
}
```

Output on console:

```
    {data: "", status: 200, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", …}
```

The way I can access the id data is by typing d.config.data.id which is not exactly what I want.

[image]

I think the problem is that get data from AngularJs in PHP file is kinda different from that using AJAX.

For AJAX, geting data literally just need to use `$_POST['id']`.
However, for AngularJS HTTP POST request, need to type something like:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

echo $data->id;
```

And here is how it look right now.

```
{data: "568", status: 200, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", …}
```

Comment: You can still use `json_encode($_POST)` to get the request as a string. http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this

```
$http({
                method:"POST",
                type:"json",
                url:"./forms/crud.php",
                data:JSON.stringify({id:cId})
            }).then(function (d) {
                alert(d.config.data.id);
                console.log(d);
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do an example for requesting data from angular and getting into php code, then getting result back.

//Angular code

```
    var url   = 'your url';
    var data  = {
          "type": "json",
    };

    //Ajax call
    $http.post(url, data).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

             var result = angular.fromJson(data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.preloader=false;

    });
```

//PHP Code

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

$request = json_decode($postdata);

echo json_encode(['data' => $this->request->data, 'status' => true, 'error' => '']);